# How to find UUID and serial number for Linux OS in java

Tags: java, linux, uuid

I am trying to find the UUID for the linux OS.
Below is the code I am trying, which is giving empty value..

```
 public static String getUUIDForLinux() {
   StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process process;
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo -S cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid"};
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
          //  process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            
        }
        log.info("uuid for linux:"+output.toString());
        return output.toString();       
}
```

For getting the serial number using the below code. Something I am doing wrong in this code..

```
  public static String getSerialNumHDForLinux() {
    String machineIdLinux = "";
    
    try {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c\"hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Serial\"");
        BufferedReader sNumReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = sNumReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        machineIdLinux =output.toString().substring(output.indexOf("\n"), output.length()).trim();
       
    }catch(IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
     return machineIdLinux;
}
```

Someone please help me to correct the code..

Comment: Read from the pseudo system files, thats a lot easier. But I cant recall what those are, and too lazy to boot up a linux; look it up ;-)

Comment: Spaces matter.  Change `"/bin/bash -c\"hdparm` to `"/bin/bash -c \"hdparm` (notice the space after the `-c`).

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Can you please [edit] your question and clarify? Just guessing: in the uuid code,  `sudo` may be asking for your password, and if you don't enter that, your code is not reading anything. `hdparm` may also need `sudo`.

Comment: You're calling `sudo` - it's probably wants to ask you for a password, but since there is no terminal attached to the stdin of the process, it doesn't execute the "cat" command. Remove sudo from the command.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for getting the UUID of linux machine.

```
 public static String getUUIDForLinux() {
   StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process process;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            
        }
        log.info("uuid for linux:"+output.toString());
        return output.toString();
```

}

For getting the serial number based on our servers I have used the following command:
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial in the above code.